# Create new record based on Old record on app maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a table:

> **Table: Client Name**
>   - id(number) Primary
>   - Client_Name(string)
>   - Client_Code(string)
>   - POC(string)

I want to create many POC with the same `Client_Name` and `Client_Code`. It should working

[image]

Its Datasource is `POCQuery` (create).

1. OnClick, I chose "*create New Item"*, it failed to create new POC. ---> failed
2. OnClick: `var record = app.models.Person.newRecord();
   app.saveRecords([record]);` ---> Failed

Actualy what I want is, everytime + button clicked. It will create new POC record bellow @POC.

Are there any suggestion to fix this problem?

Comment: I also try with this but it also failed : var myCreateDatasource = app.datasources.ClientName.modes.create;
var draft = myCreateDatasource.item;

draft.Client_Name = app.datasources.ClientName.item.Client_Name;
draft.Client_Code = app.datasources.ClientName.item.Client_Code;

myCreateDatasource.createItem(function(newRecord) {
   // Callback is called after the record is saved, so it now has a key.
   var key = newRecord._key;
   // Do something with the key here.
   draft.POC = app.datasources.ClientName.item.POC;
 });

Comment: Is POC a relation to ClientName or a field? It seems you are wanting to create a relation but are treating it like a field.

Comment: POC is field in ClientName

Comment: Is your datasource by chance a ‘manual save’ datasource? If that’s the case you need to call saveChanges() on your datasource after the createItem().